# Editing Table Cell Style

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]How can I make custom editing style table cell ?
I found

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewCellEditingStyle) {
    UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone,
    UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete,
    UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert
};
```

but I need 2 buttons and to make it custom.

i need change system cell edit (mode UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete). Delete button replace  to 2 my custom buttons

Comment: you should custom yourself.

Comment: This question is a bit vague. Provide more detail about what you are trying to accomplish.